# Timing quick sort algorithm

Tags: java, quicksort

Hey I seem to be having a problem trying to implement some Java quick sort code over an array of 10,000 random numbers. I have a text file containing the numbers which are placed into an array, which is then passed to the sorting algorithm to be sorted. My aim is to time how long it takes to time the sorting increasing the numbers sorted each time using the timing loop I have. But for some reason using this code gives me a curved graph instead of a straight linear line. I know the timing loop and array code work fine so there seems to be a problem with the sorting code but can't seem to find anything! Any help is greatly appreciated thanks!

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Quicksort {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
//Import the random integer text file into an integer array
File fil = new File("randomASC.txt");
FileReader inputFil = new FileReader(fil);
int [] myarray = new int [10000];
Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFil);

for(int q = 0; q < myarray.length; q++)
{
  myarray[q] = in.nextInt();
}
in.close();



for (int n = 100; n < 10000; n += 100) { 
long total = 0;
for (int r = 0; r < 10; ++r) {  
  long start = System.nanoTime ();    
      quickSort(myarray,0,n-1);
      total += System.nanoTime() - start;
    }
  System.out.println (n + "," + (double)total / 10.0);
} 
}

 public static void quickSort(int[] a, int p, int r)
{
    if(p<r)
    {
        int q=partition(a,p,r);
        quickSort(a,p,q);
        quickSort(a,q+1,r);
    }
}

private static int partition(int[] a, int p, int r) {

    int x = a[p];
    int i = p-1 ;
    int j = r+1 ;

    while (true) {
        i++;
        while ( i< r && a[i] < x)
            i++;
        j--;
        while (j>p && a[j] > x)
            j--;

        if (i < j)
            swap(a, i, j);
        else
            return j;
    }
}

private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the first iteration of the inner loop actually sorts the array that you've read from the file. All the subsequent iterations are applied to the already-sorted array.

> But for some reason using this code gives me a curved graph instead of a straight linear line.

If you mean that the run time grows non-linearly in `n`, that's to be expected since quicksort is not a linear-time algorithm (no comparison sort is).

Your performance graph looks like a nice quadratic function:

[image: Performance graph]

You're getting quadratic rather than `O(n log(n))` time due to your choice of pivot: since most of the time you're calling your function on a sorted array, your method of choosing the pivot means you're hitting the worst case every single time.

Comment: does that mean that it's sorted first time then that sorted array is done again over and over? Even if the array size is changed each time?

Comment: @burgergetsbored: Sorry, I was talking about the inner loop. You can't expect the time to grow linearly in `n` since quicksort is not a linear-time algorithm.

Comment: The aim was to use the inner loop to gain an average then use the outer loop to keep changing the amount of values being sorted. How would I go about setting a new array each time as when I tried placing it inside a new method it gave errors about being able to access the array

Comment: @burgergetsbored: That's a nice quadratic function. You're getting quadratic rather than `O(n log(n))` due to your choice of pivot: since most of the time you're calling your function on a sorted array, your choice of pivot is the worst possible one.